# Slick Slide script not transforming to slickslide

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Hi i would like to seek help for as my slick slider is not functioning correct i get a sample from the keenweeler site but seems not working on my part here is my code.There is no error issue that is showing on the debug console so i was puzzled what was wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/pynechan/xhpfgzwy/9/

```
//CDN
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css"/>    



     // video slide JS
    $(".videoslide").slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        autoplay:false,
        arrows: true;
    });


<div class="videoslide">
        <div class="slides">
          <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="slides">
          <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="slides">
          <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="slides">
          <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="slides">
          <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="slides">
          <img src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
        </div>
</div>

    /* Carousel CSS */

    .videoslide {
        width: 650px;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .videoslide img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your jquery code with this it will work

```
 $(".videoslide").slick({

        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of "arrows: true" and it will work.
So the finished script looks like this:

```
$(".videoslide").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay:false,
    arrows: true
});
```