# Slack Slider not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to create a slack slider but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I am doing something wrong but I feel like I will need some extra javascript and just the default code from the slick documentation won't be enough.

Here is a quick codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rROXJQ

```
<section class="success-stories scrollspy" id="success-story">
    <div class="">
        <div class="slick1 success-banner slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted"><button class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" type="button" style="display: inline-block;">Previous</button><div class="slick-list draggable" style="padding: 0px 50px;"><div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 20000px; transform: translate3d(-1247px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a class="waves-effect btn" href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" tabindex="-1">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        03
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6></h6>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum by Budget Lorem Ipsum.</span>
                        <p>WLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <!--<a class="waves-effect btn" >READ MORE</a>-->

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        04
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6></h6>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active slick-center" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum reaches Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" class="waves-effect btn" tabindex="0">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        01
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">
                        <audio preload="none" class="audio-tag">
                            <source src="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" type="audio/mpeg">
                        </audio>
                        <a href="#" class="audio-trigger" tabindex="0">play!</a>
                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6>Lorem Ipsum</h6>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide11"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>FLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a class="waves-effect btn" href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" tabindex="-1">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        02
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6>Lorem Ipsum &amp; Lorem Ipsums</h6>
                            <p>FirstJob Lorem Ipsum</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide12"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a class="waves-effect btn" href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" tabindex="-1">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        03
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6></h6>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide13"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum by Lorem Ipsum.</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <!--<a class="waves-effect btn" >READ MORE</a>-->

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        04
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6></h6>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">BLorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Valued at $Lorem Ipsum (and growing). Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumInvests.
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" class="waves-effect btn" tabindex="-1">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        01
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">
                        <audio preload="none" class="audio-tag">
                            <source src="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" type="audio/mpeg">
                        </audio>
                        <a href="#" class="audio-trigger" tabindex="-1">play!</a>
                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6>Lorem Ipsum</h6>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsumt Founder</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="5" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>FLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum.
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a class="waves-effect btn" href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" tabindex="-1">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        02
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6>Lorem Ipsum &amp; Lorem Ipsum</h6>
                            <p>Lorem IpsumFounders</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide slick-cloned slick-center" data-slick-index="6" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum wins prestigious Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum times by Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <a class="waves-effect btn" href="https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1" tabindex="-1">READ MORE</a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        03
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6></h6>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div><div class="slick-slide slick-cloned" data-slick-index="7" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1"><div><div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-content ">
                        <span class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Direct.</span>
                        <p>Weather Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum for Lorem Ipsum.
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <!--<a class="waves-effect btn" >READ MORE</a>-->

                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-num">
                        04
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-pic" style="background-image:url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/jeff-bezos-bpoy-2016.jpg?w=820&h=570&crop=1');">

                        <div class="pic-caption">
                            <h6></h6>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div></div></div></div><button class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" type="button" style="display: block; margin-left: -25px;">p</button><ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block; min-width: 120px; margin-left: 30px;" role="tablist"><li class="slick-active" role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control10" aria-controls="slick-slide10" aria-label="1 of 4" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li><li role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control11" aria-controls="slick-slide11" aria-label="2 of 4" tabindex="-1">2</button></li><li role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control12" aria-controls="slick-slide12" aria-label="3 of 4" tabindex="-1">3</button></li><li role="presentation"><button type="button" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control13" aria-controls="slick-slide13" aria-label="4 of 4" tabindex="-1">4</button></li></ul></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS Section :

```
$('.slick1').slick({
centerMode: true,
centerPadding: '60px',
slidesToShow: 3,
responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 768,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '40px',
    slidesToShow: 3
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '40px',
    slidesToShow: 1
  }
}
```

]
  });

Comment: May be you also need slidesToScroll:3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/54779488/10634638

Comment: Your HTML example above seems to have all the initialized slick slider code in it. Is that the code you have in your source?

Comment: @bestinamir I tried adding slidesToScroll but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @jaasum Yes this is the code that I have in my source. Its the exact same as the codepeon

Comment: Please try to simplify, removing lines to make it closer to my example link..

Comment: You may want to go back to the [docs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and make sure your source markup matches what the docs says, without the generated code in it.